# In 64 bit and 32 bit OS they have different result

Tags: operating-system, byte, system, typedef, bit

[image]

I want to be ensured my thought.

1. The picture is 32 bit representation(32 bit OS). So each memory array has 32 bits memory since each hexadecimal digit has 16 bits. Am i right?
2. I can't totally understand result of this code in terms of 64 bit OS Is it right **each memory slot has 32 bit and 64 bit in each OS?**

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   typedef int *byte_pointer

   void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, size_t len){
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    printf(" |%.2x",start[i]);
   printf("\n");
   }

    void show_int(int x){
   show_bytes((byte_pointer) &x, sizeof(int));

   }

   int main(){

   show_int(12345);  //3039 in hexadecimal

   }
   ```

I think the result should be |30390000 | ......|.......|......

But the result is | 3039 | ......|.......|...... in real
I thought int is 4 byte = 32bit so it should print 8 digits in hexadecimal since one digit in hexadecimal holds 4 bit. Where is wrong? plz correct my thought....

Answer (score -1):

Ad 1: Each blue cell in the image represents a memory cell which is 1 byte in size. The numbers have 2 hex digits because the maximum number that can be stored in one byte is 255 or FF in hex. Four memory cells are together 32 bits in size, yes.

Ad 2: No. Each memory slot has 1 byte, on 32 bit as well as on 64 bit operating systems. But an integer is stored in several consecutive memory cells. On 32 bit OSs an int is usually stored in 4 consecutive memory cells, on 64 bit OSs an int is stored in 8 consecutive memory cells. If you want to print the individual memory cells of your number you must loop over an array of chars (a char is of size 1 byte):

```
void show_bytes(byte_pointer start, size_t len){
int i;
for(i=0; i<len; i++)
 printf(" |%.2x",((char *)start)[i]);
printf("\n");
}
```

This prints e.g.:

```
 |39 |30 |00 |00
```

Edit: The size of an int is not explicitly specified in the C standard. It could also be 4 byte on a 64 bit OS. If you want to use 8 byte integers, you can try `long long` instead of `int`.

Answer (score -1):

64-bits and 32-bits refer to the basic unit of processing in the CPU. They do not affect the size of elements of arrays.

Your image addresses byte ordering, which is an entirely different concept.

If you have the integer value (hex) 89AB that requires two bytes, does 89 or AB go into there first byte?

That answer depends upon the processor. Some processors put the most significant byte first so that 89 comes before AB in memory.

Some processor put the least significant byte fist in memory so that AB comes before 89.

(And some processors are configurable so that the operating system can select which ordering to use at startup.)

> The picture is 32 bit representation(32 bit OS). So each memory array has 32 bits memory since each hexadecimal digit has 16 bits. Am i right?

No, nearly every processor supports integers of different sizes. That image could reflect a 16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit ..... processor.

> I can't totally understand result of this code in terms of 64 bit OS Is it right each memory slot has 32 bit and 64 bit in each OS?

No. All (nearly all?) modern processors operate on 8-bit bytes.

The purpose of your sample code is so show the byte ordering on the processor. It has nothing to do with 32-bits v. 64-bits EXCEPT that compilers tend to use the natural integer size for the processor. But that is a compiler specific thing and not a processor thing.

You say you are getting

```
|39 |30 |00 |00
```

I am going to guess you are using an Intel or Intel compatible processor. If you run that on a 68000 you are going to get

```
|00 |00 |30 |39
```

Comment: I wonder why it has different result depending on whether **typedef int *byte_pointer;**  or  **typedef unsigned char *byte_pointer**                                         Is it same with two cases that each memory cell hold just **1 byte right?**  what effect does it have on different pointer type ???

Comment: That alters the number of bytes it prints out at a time.